# How do I get my autodesk extension to appear?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Been having an issue with this step of the autodesk tutorial, ForgeTree and ForgeViewer work just fine, but I cant get the handleselectionextension to work at all, no menu or toolbar shows up just an empty window

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/selection

main.css

```
.handleSelectionExtensionIcon {
    background-image: url(https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/raw/master/white/png/24/object-group.png);
    background-size: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

index.html

```
<!-- this project files -->
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/ForgeTree.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ForgeViewer.js"></script>
  
  <script src="js/handleselectionextension.js"></script>
```

the extension is just the one shown in the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the extension in Forge viewer.

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['HandleSelectionExtension'] });
```

After that you can call below code on click button for isolating the selected objects.

```
// Get current selection
const selection = this.viewer.getSelection();
this.viewer.clearSelection();
// Anything selected?
if (selection.length > 0) {
    let isolated = [];
    // Iterate through the list of selected dbIds
    selection.forEach((dbId) => {
        // Get properties of each dbId
        this.viewer.getProperties(dbId, (props) => {
            // Output properties to console
            console.log(props);
            // Ask if want to isolate
            if (confirm(`Isolate ${props.name} (${props.externalId})?`)) {
                isolated.push(dbId);
                this.viewer.isolate(isolated);
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    // If nothing selected, restore
    this.viewer.isolate(0);
}
```